# Way to distinguish different AJAX functions in POST?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

I need to distinguish among multiple AJAX functions in a django view's POST method, to handle multiple forms.

**The background:**

I'd previously written this view without AJAX and got it working just fine.  Before Ajax, I was able to distinguish the POST method for each form by adding name="some_button_name", like so:

```
if request.method == 'POST' and 'some_button_name' in request.POST: #check which form button submitted
```

This was great, but AJAX can make it better if I get it working. Now I'm not sure how to distinguish the ajax functions on the view side.

Here's how I *think* it should work (theoretical view):

```
if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST['some identifier_A from ajax function here']:
    # do stuff
    # save form_A
if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST['some identifier_B from ajax function here']:
    # do stuff
    # save form_B
if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST['some identifier_C from ajax function  here']:
    # do stuff
    # save form_C
```

... but I'm stumped.  Below is my (simplified but structurally accurate) code.  It will of course want to call every model's save method regardless of which form/ajax function was called, so saving *form C* will screw up *form B* since the B's ajax handler didn't do anything or pass any JSON.

I've looked through the list of ajax parameters and it doesn't appear that I can use one to add some identifying variable to catch on the view side in POST... or is there?

If someone could shed some light a way to solve this I'd be hugely appreciative.  Also, I'm not sure if it's relevant to this question, but I also want to eventually add a "save all" button that fires all the ajax functions.

**Views.py**

```
def update_view(request, slug):

    mymodel = Model.objects.get(slug=slug)

    form_A  = Model_A_Form(instance=mymodel.model_a)
    form_B  = Model_B_Form(instance=mymodel.model_b)
    form_C  = Model_C_Form(instance=mymodel.model_c)

    if request.method == 'POST': # using request.is_ajax(): here causes the same problem

        form_A = Model_A_Form(request.POST, instance=mymodel.model_a)
        if form_A.is_valid():
            form_A.save()
            return JsonResponse

        form_B = Model_B_Form(request.POST, instance=mymodel.model_b)
        if form_B.is_valid():
            form_B.save() 
            return JsonResponse

        form_C = Model_C_Form(request.POST, instance=mymodel.model_c)
        if form_C.is_valid():
            form_C.save() 
            return JsonResponse

    context = {

        'form_A': form_A,
        'form_B': form_B,
        'form_C': form_C,
        'obj': mymodel,
    }

    return render(request, "products/update_form.html", context)
```

**.JS**

```
<script>
    $(() => {

        // Form A handler

        $(function () {
            $('#mybtn-a').click(function () {
                var formA = $(".form-a-ajax")
                var formAMethod = formA.attr("method");
                var formAEndpoint = formA.attr("action");
                formA.submit(function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var formAData = formA.serialize()
                    var thisForm = $(this)
                    $.ajax({
                        method: formAMethod,
                        url: formAEndpoint,
                        data: formAData,
                        success: function (data) {
                            $.alter({
                                title: "Success!",
                            })
                        },
                        error: function (error) {

                        }

                    }) //end ajax
                });//end click
            })
        })

        // Form B handler

        $(function () { 
            $('#mybtn-b').click(function () {
                var formB = $(".form-b-ajax")
                var formBMethod = formB.attr("method");
                var formBEndpoint = formB.attr("action")
                formB.submit(function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var formBData = formB.serialize()
                    var thisForm = $(this)
                    $.ajax({
                        method: formBMethod,
                        url: formBEndpoint,
                        data: formBData,

                        success: function (data) {
                            $.alter({
                                title: "Success!",
                            })
                        },
                        error: function (error) {

                        }

                    }) // end ajax
                });//end click
            })
        })

        // Form C handler

        $(function () {
            $('#mybtn-c').click(function () {
                var formC = $(".form-c-ajax")
                var formCMethod = formC.attr("method");
                var formCEndpoint = formC.attr("action")
                formC.submit(function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var formCData = formC.serialize()
                    var thisForm = $(this)
                    $.ajax({
                        method: formCMethod,
                        url: formCEndpoint,
                        data: formCData,

                        success: function (data) {
                            $.alter({
                                title: "Success!",
                            })
                        },
                        error: function (error) {

                        }

                    }) //end ajax
                });//end click
            })
        })
```

**Template:**

```
<form method="post" action="{{ obj.get_my_url }}" class="form-a-ajax">
    {% csrf_token %} {{ form_A }}
    <button type='submit' id="mybtn-a" name='save_form_a' class='btn btn-success'>Save</button>
</form>

<form method="post" action="{{ obj.get_my_url }}" class="form-b-ajax">
    {% csrf_token %} {{ form_B }}
    <button type='submit' id="mybtn-b" name='save_form_b' class='btn btn-success'>Save</button>
</form>

<form method="post" action="{{ obj.get_my_url }}" class="form-c-ajax">
    {% csrf_token %} {{ form_C }}
    <button type='submit' id="mybtn-c" name='save_form_c' class='btn btn-success'>Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: There are several ways to do this. You could put a hidden input in each form with a unique value that identifies the form or you could just append a value on to the end of your formData after you serialize the form like `formCData += '&formName=c'`.

Comment: Yes with hidden inputs with same name and unique value for each form!  You can also add to ajax params, for Ex : target:FormA then switch based on target values...

Comment: you could just convert  button type='submit' to input type='submit' and put same name and different values and just check value in django based on value you just choose the form

Comment: Thanks all for the comments.  I'm going to attempt some of these solutions.  @Bilel, could you share some more detail about adding an ajax parameter?

Comment: something like in your example here where formAData has the serialized content  [data : formAData + "&target=FormA"] then a switch or a conditional check on target value would do the job ;) This assumes you your ajax  type:'POST'. There is also jQuery param that we could use here https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your feedback everybody! Your comments gave me an idea.  I have a working solution and it seems totally simple after the fact.  No need to append anything to the JSON in my case.  Every model I have has some unique field names; I just need to check for the presence of one of them in the JSON object of key:value pairs.  This works:

```
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'some_unique_model_field_name' in request.POST.keys():

        form_A = Model_A_Form(request.POST, instance=mymodel.model_a)
        if form_A.is_valid():
            form_A.save()
            return JsonResponse

        #rinse and repeat...
```